# What is the best way to tag images for use in other channels?

Tags: search, sort

Here is my scenario: I have over 1,000 untagged images that I need to be able to sort and search in order to use in my entries.

I am looking at tagger by DevDemon but then I can only look for one tag at a time in the "Content->Edit" page. (Unless I'm missing something).

What I'd like would be the ability to add multiple tags fairly easily (Or easy for me to make forms that will create/updates the entries). Plus the ability to then search for the images using more than one tag (so I want to look for images that are tagged with both "men" and "hard hat"). When I do that search, I'd like the results to show the image (or a thumbnail).

Do any of you know of anything out there that already does this? I will build it if I need to but just hate to reinvent the wheel.

thanks!

Comment: forgot - I'd really like to be able to look at a few pictures at a time and click on tags next to each of them to get them into the database. Kind of like Mechanical Turk.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Assets (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/assets) by Pixel & Tonic. It allows to you add metadata for each image which you can use for "tagging".